# Проблема в игре "Крестики Нолики"

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Запуская игру, я ввожу `X` или `O`, потом вводятся только мои буквы, а ИИ нет и когда я выигрываю выскакивают эти ошибки:

> line 54, in getBoardCopy
> return BoardCopy NameError: name 'BoardCopy' is not defined
>
> line 91, in getComputerMove
> boardCopy = getBoardCopy(board)
>
> line 156, in 
> move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)

Можете скопировать код и запустить игру отдельно, чтобы увидеть ошибку.

```
# Крестики-нолики

import random

def drawBoard(board):
    # Эта функция выводит на экран игровое поле, клетки которого будут заполняться.
    
    # "board" - это список из 10 строк, для прорисовки игрового поля (индекс 0 игнорируется).
    print(board[7] + '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board[4] + '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board[1] + '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
def inputPlayerLetter():
    # Рзарешение игроку ввести букву, которую он выбирает.
    # Возвращает список, в котором буква игрока - первый элемент, а буква компьютера - второй.
    letter = ''
    while not(letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Вы выбираете X или O?')
        letter = input().upper()
    # Первым элементом списка является бувка игрока, вторым - буква компьютера.
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X','O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

def whoGoesFirst():
    # Случайным выбор игрока, который ходит первым.
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        return 'Компьютер'
    else:
        return 'Человек'
    
def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter
    
def isWinner(bo, le):
    # Учитывая заполнение игрового поля и буквы игрока, эта функция возвращает True, если игрок выиграл.
    # Мы используем "bo" вместо "board" и "le" вместо "letter", поэтому нам не нужно иного печатать.
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or
    (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or
    (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) 
    
def getBoardCopy(board):
    # Создаёт копию игрового поля и возвращает его.
    boardCopy = []
    for i in board:
        boardCopy.append(i)
    return BoardCopy

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
    # Возвращает True, если сделан ход в свободную клетку.
    return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
    # Разрешение  игроку сделать ход.
    move = ' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
        print('Ваш следующий ход? (1-9)')
        move = input()
    return int(move)
    
def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, movesList):
    # Возвращает допустимый ход, учитывая список сделанных ходов и список заполненных клеток.
    # Возвращает значение None, если больше нет допустимых ходов.
    possibleMoves = []
    for i in movesList:
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            possibleMoves.append(i)
            
    if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
        return random.choice(possibleMoves)
    else:
        return None
    
def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
    # Учитывая заполнение игрового поля и букву компьютера, определяет допустимый код и возвращает его.
    if computerLetter == 'X':
        playerLetter == 'O'
    else:
        playerLetter == 'X'
        
    # Это алгоритм для ИИ "Крестиков-Ноликов"
    # Сначала проверяем - победим ли мы, сделав следующий код.
    for i in range(1, 10):
        boardCopy = getBoardCopy(board)
        if isSpaceFree(boardCopy, i):
            makeMove(boardCopy, computerLetter, i)
            if isWinner (boardCopy, computerLetter):
                return i
            
    # Проверяем - победит ли игрок, сделав следующий ход, и блокируем его.
    for i in range(1,10):
        boardCopy = getBoardCopy(board)
        if isSpaceFree(boardCopy, i):
            makeMove(boardCopy, playerLetter, i)
            if isWinner (boardCopy, playerLetter):
                return i
            
    # Пробуем занять центр один из углов, если есть свободные.
    move = chooseRandomMoveFromList (board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
    if move != None:
        return move
    
    # Пробуем занять центр, если он свободен.
    if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
        return 5
    
    # Делаем ход по одной стороне.
    return chooseRandomMoveFromList (board, [2, 4, 6, 8])

def isBoardFull(board):
    # Возвращает True, если клетка на игровом поле занята. В противном случае, возвращает False.
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            return False
    return True
    
    
print('Игра "Крестики-нолики"')

while True:
    # Презагрузка игрового поля
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('' + turn + ' ходит первым.')
    gameIsPlaying = True
    
    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'Человек':
            # Ход игрока.
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)
        
            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Ура! Вы выиграли!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
        else:
            if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Ничья!')
                break
            else:
                turn = 'Компьютер'
                
    else:
        # Ход компьютера.
        move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
        makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)
        
        if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('Компьютер победил! Вы проиграли.')
            gameIsPlaying = False
        else:
            if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Ничья')
                break
            else:
                turn = 'Человек'
            
    print('Сыграем ещё раз раз? (да или нет)')
    if not input().lower().startswith('д'):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `getBoardCopy` вы возвращаете `BoardCopy`, хотя создаёте `boardCopy`. Python чувствителен к регистру.

Код с исправлением

```py
def getBoardCopy(board):
    # Создаёт копию игрового поля и возвращает его.
    boardCopy = []
    for i in board:
        boardCopy.append(i)
    return boardCopy
```

Также у вас нарушена табуляция в цикле `while gameIsPlaying:`. Из-за неправильного определения if-else(из-за табуляции) у вас получался бесконечный цикл. Это тоже поправил

```py
while True:
    # Перезагрузка игрового поля
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('' + turn + ' ходит первым.')
    gameIsPlaying = True
    
    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'Человек':
            # Ход игрока.
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)
        
            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Ура! Вы выиграли!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('Ничья!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'Компьютер'
                
        else:
            # Ход компьютера.
            move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
            makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)
        
            if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Компьютер победил! Вы проиграли.')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('Ничья')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'Человек'
            
    print('Сыграем ещё раз раз? (да или нет)')
    if not input().lower().startswith('д'):
        break
```

Comment: Я ввожу букву и пишет "Компьютер ходит первым" и ничего не выводится

Comment: @ILYA558 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое ;)